# GET request with 404 causing additional load times on my site - How do I fix it?

Tags: css, datepicker, get, request

When visiting my site I have a huge GET request that takes about 8 seconds to load before it is aborted. I have no idea what it's referring to and am looking for a way to stop it so my page loads faster.

Link: https://partyheadphones.com/rent-selfie-station/

Chrome error: GET https://partyheadphones.com/admin/css/datepicker.css?v=913-new-social-icons54914e2ef10782de net::ERR_ABORTED 404

I've searched the Index.php file and can't find a reference to this, so not sure what to do here.

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same issue on my website. The quick fix was to upload an empty datepicker.css. There was no such folder named admin/css in my case, so I had to create one. Even though this fixed the website loading issue, it's is just a temporary workaround. I hope someone would come up with a solution that solves the root cause.
Cheers!